# Allowing authenticated users to create files through Service/Restful

Tags: 7, nodes, users, services

I have setup a restful server running with the services module.  I have also enabled to file resource.  Using this setup I can successfully login from my client application, authenticate the session, upload a file using the file resource and then create a node with node resource.  This all works fine and good as long as I am authenticated with an adminstrator but if I ever try and use a standard authenticated user I get this error back in response from the file resource:

```
Unauthorized: Access denied for user authuser
```

I looked all throughout the user permissions but I did not see any permission to allow authenticated users to create files.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure "Save file information" is set for authenticated users